# Windows phone 7 - preserving application state

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone

Scenario:

User completes some action which sends SMS. Application raises a message box with two buttons. User then leaves the application and checks if he/she got a reply SMS. User then starts application again and its in the same state as when the user left it - message box is still open.

So what I actually need is preserving application/page state.

What are my options for this?

Comment: Read this on how to save/restore state: [WP7 Tombstoning Pattern Tip](http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/08/22/WP7-Tombstoning-Pattern-Tip.aspx). You can implement your criteria on when a save needs to be done.

Comment: This is not about multithreading but instead about preserving state you might want to edit the title and the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing would be to use IsolatedStorageSettings to preserve whether or not the user was waiting for a code or not: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=VS.95).aspx